# Run Custom Outlook addin functionalities in a separate thread without making outlook to hang

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, outlook-addin

In my custom outlook addin which is featured with a taskpane loading(hosting) a WPF user control which contains some textboxes and login button.

this is my login button click event handler

```
private void lblbtnLogin_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {

                //this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>Login()));
                this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync((Action)(() => Login()));
                //Thread loginThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Login));
                //loginThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                //loginThread.IsBackground = true;
                //loginThread.Start();
                //th.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                string msg = exp.Message;
            }
        }
```

and the login method code is

```
public void Login()
        {
            try
            {
                if (txtWSUrl.Text == "Enter WebService URL" || txtWSUrl.Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("WebService URL Cannot be Empty", string.Empty, MessageBoxButton.OK);
                }
                else if (txtEmailId.Text == "Enter Email ID" || txtEmailId.Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Email ID Cannot be Empty", string.Empty, MessageBoxButton.OK);
                }
                else if (txtPwd.Password == "********" || txtPwd.Password == string.Empty)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Password Cannot be Empty", string.Empty, MessageBoxButton.OK);
                }
                else
                {
                    Globals.ThisAddIn.url = txtWSUrl.Text;
                    Summit_BLL.ProxyParamDetails ppd = new Summit_BLL.ProxyParamDetails();
                    ppd.UserName = txtEmailId.Text;
                    ppd.Password = txtPwd.Password;
                    CommonParameters cp = new CommonParameters();
                    cp._ProxyDetails = ppd;

                    //Summit_RESTWCF rest = new Summit_RESTWCF();
                    //string o=rest.LoginApp(ppd);

                    string strJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cp);
                    string strMethod = "LoginApp";
                    string output = WSConsumer.GetWSResult(ref strJson, ref strMethod);

                    OutputParam op = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OutputParam>(output);
                    if (op.Errors == string.Empty)
                    {
                        string objJson = op.Output;
                        AppUser obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppUser>(objJson);
                        if (obj.User.UserDetails.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (UserDetail ud in obj.User.UserDetails)
                            {

                            }
                        }
                        //string Feedback = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["App:RequiredFeedbackModule"].IsNotNullAndEmpty() ? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["App:RequiredFeedbackModule"].ToString().ToUpper() : "NULL";
                        WPFUCMaster master = WPFUCMaster.Instance;
                        WPFUCHome home = new WPFUCHome();
                        master.AddControl(home);
                        //System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(op.Errors, string.Empty, MessageBoxButton.OK);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                string msg = exp.Message;
            }
        }
```

here i tried with the dispatcher and as well as with the new thread while im running this also the outlook will be hanged or not responding untill the next screen gets loaded.

if i use new thread and pass Login method for constructor its throwing an exception like

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: this is normal, UI items cannot be accessed or more specifically changed from outside the UI thread.